# Get posts that have both categories

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make an array that holds all the pages of the site that have both the category `big` as well as `insect`.

Currently it looks like this

```
<?php
$argsposts = array(
    'category_name' => 'big'
); 
$posts = get_posts($argsposts);
?>
```

And it successfully gets all the posts with the category `big` however I would like to update it to only get posts with the category `big` if they also have the category `insect`.

Comment: I'm always more intend to use a `tax_query` for mutliple term or taxonomy handling. You have more control with a `tax_query` than with the category parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=big+insect' );
```

This is [right in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

> Display posts that have "all" of these categories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$big_cat = get_category_by_slug('big');
$insect_cat = get_category_by_slug('insect');
$argsposts = array(
  'category__and' => array($big_cat->term_id, $insect_cat->term_id)
  );
$posts = get_posts($argsposts);
```

Comment: This is ineffecient and you should avoid it if possible.

Comment: I just saw mevius answer, it seems more efficient indeed. Didn't thought that it would have been possible.